# Best way to typeset “T_n-space”

Tags: symbols

In topology, one often talks about spaces satisfying various separation conditions such as T₀-spaces. When I have to type “T₀-space” in LaTeX, I write

```tex
T$_0$-space
```

but I think using the mathematical mode this way is bit of a hack. I suppose I could also write

```tex
$\text{T}_0$-space
```

but this doesn't feel like what `\text{}` is supposed to be used for either.

My question is: what would be a completely hack-free way of typesetting this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I wouldn't use `$\text{T}_{0}$` because the `\text` responds to the surrounding font. Depending on whether or not the T should be upright or italic, I'd either go with `$\mathrm{T}_{0}$` or `$T_{0}$`. (Define a macro for the "T", so you can things easily later in case you change your mind about the italic/non-italic issue)

Comment: In a quick Google search I just ran, most documents typeset with LaTeX (or with LaTeX-like syntax, i.e. with MathJax and friends) seem to use `$T_{0}$`, but I don't know if that is because most people are lazy and prefer to write `$T_{0}$` over longer stuff like `$\mathrm{T}_{0}$` or because there is a real preference for an italic T here.

Comment: you do want math mode but want the T to be math as well so the subscript is kerned under the T, $\mathrm{T}_0$-space would be the standard markup I think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you (a) load the `amsmath` package for its `\nobreakdash` macro and (b) define a macro called `\Tsp` (you're free to come up with a different name...) as follows:

```
\newcommand{\Tsp}[1][0]{$\mathrm{T}_{\!#1}$\nobreakdash-space}
```

The `\Tsp` macro is set up to take one, optional argument, whose default value is `0`. Note that if this macro is to be used in math mode, it should be encased in a `\text` directive. The `\nobreakdash` macro forbids line breaks at the `-` ("dash") symbol, as I assume it's not ok to allow a linebreak between `T_0` and `space`.

[image]

Observe that a "negative thinspace" kern is inserted between `\mathrm{T}` and its subscript argument. If that places the symbols too close to each other, consider replacing `\!` with `\mkern-2mu`. (`\!` is equivalent to `\mkern-3mu`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Tsp}[1][0]{$\mathrm{T}_{\!#1}$\nobreakdash-space}
\begin{document}
\Tsp, \Tsp[1], \Tsp[n]

$\dotsc\text{ \Tsp[2] }\dotsc$
\end{document}
```